# How do I get the file path of an iTunes Selection

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I'm trying to determine the path of track selected in iTunes using AppleScript. It doesn't seem to be a property of the `track` class. Can anyone tell me how I can get the file path?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
--gets file path of selected song
tell application "iTunes"
 set songLocation to get location of selection
end tell
return songLocation

--gets file path of currently playing song
tell application "iTunes"
 set songLocation to get location of current track
end tell
return songLocation
```

Comment: The `file track` class, which inherits from the `track` class, adds the `location` property (which a track from a shared library may not have, for example), which contains the path to the file.  So you may want to first check the type first, using this: `if class of myTrack is not file track then...`.  Incidentally, if the track is "orphaned" - the file is not found - the `location = missing value`, which can be checked against to locate orphaned files.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not available through AppleScript, your best bet will be to open and parse the iTunes plist file. If you only need static information, you're golden. If you need dynamic information (for example, info on the track that's currently playing), you'll want to get the track's ***persistent ID*** through AppleScript, then parse the plist file and lookup any info you need (including *location*, which has the full path).

For parsing that plist XML file (in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml), you can use ruby or python or any other language you like. If you like python, try this library:

http://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Python instead of AppleScript and don't want to parse the plist XML file, you can get the file path through the COM API.

```
import win32com.client

iTunes = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("iTunes.Application")
currentTrack = win32com.client.CastTo(iTunes.CurrentTrack,"IITFileOrCDTrack")

print currentTrack.Location
```